# How to Create Magento 2 Multiple Languages?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, language, magento-2.0.7, multiple

I want to create my store in multiple Languages. But I can not do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this tutorial which iI 've found it on Venustheme:
http://www.venustheme.com/magento-multiple-languages/

*1. Create Magento 2 multiple Languages*
You should create for these following steps:

- Create store
- Create store view
- Create Language

Firstly, Login *Magento 2 Admin Panel >>> Store >>> Create store*:

Then fill the blank: store information like the picture >>> Save store
- Create store view: 
Fill all and enable language inside:

*2. Create Magento  2 multiple Currencies*

*Currency set up >>> At currencies option: Choose like Euro (at allow currencies) >>> Save config
Store >>> Currency rate *
At import service choose *“Import” >>> Save currency rates*